# yarn client setEnvironment does not work at all?

Tags: hadoop-yarn

I tried to write an yarn application and submit it by client.

I set the env as following.

```
ContainerLaunchContext containerLaunchContext = Records.newRecord(ContainerLaunchContext.class);

 for (String setting : settings) {
            Apps.addToEnvironment(appMasterEnv, ApplicationConstants.Environment.CLASSPATH.name(),
                    setting.trim());
        }
        Apps.addToEnvironment(appMasterEnv, ApplicationConstants.Environment.CLASSPATH.name(),
                ApplicationConstants.Environment.PWD.$() + File.separator + "*.jar");

        containerLaunchContext.setEnvironment(appMasterEnv);
```

and set the command as `ls -al && echo $CLASSPATH && java com.zw.am.AMImpl`

The env `classpath` does not exists at all. any one know how to fix it.

by the way, the application got failed as could not load the main class.

Comment: I found out the reason, I found that I set the env again .